# How to align anchor tags in one line using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I want to align my links in one line but I have no idea how to do it.

Here's my code:

```
<div class=col-sm-4>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="form-group btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
        <form action="EditMyFoundItem" method="POST">
            <input type="Hidden" name="found_id"  value="${myFoundList.getFoundID()}">   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Edit</button> 
        </form>
        <form action="CommentFoundItem" method="POST">
            <input type="HIDDEN" name="found_id" value="${myFoundList.getFoundID()}">  
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Add Comment</button> 
        </form>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwa7o.png)

I want my links to look like this:

```
Edit   Add Comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Class `pull-left` for form tag

```
<form action="EditMyFoundItem" class="pull-left" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thank you! what does pull-left mean?

Comment: pull-left  mean  float:left